# ActionBarSherlock action bar won't hide in Dialog

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I am loading an activity that has  `ActionBarSherlock` implemented. As the activity begins to load I show a splash screen with the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/splash"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splashlogo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Before loading the splash screen I call

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

I have even tried:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

But no matter what I do I always get the following on my splash screen:

[image]

Is there something I need to add or am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you given any delay for showing the splash screen??

Comment: It is shown directly after 'super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);'

Comment: In you splashscreen befor the `setcontentView` line write `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: Using `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` worked! write up an answer. @GrlsHu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your splashscreen before the `dialog.setcontentView` line write

```
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```